# Change Query Timeout on Snowflake Warehouse

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using Snowflake to run a rather long query, but my queries are timing out after 15 minutes. I'm pretty sure the warehouse is set to a short timeout length. How do I modify the query timeout amount?

The error I get is `SQL execution canceled`.

I have run the same query multiple times. Each time, it stops after 15 minutes. I have also included a 'limit' rows parameter, and it finished after 12 minutes (but with less data than what I really need) - so I'm very confident that the query works, but it takes longer than 15 minutes to run.

From this [document](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-session) I fond a way to change the timeout *for this session only*, but I'd like to be able to change the timeout *for the entire warehouse* so no one else has this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ALTER WAREHOUSE to change the STATEMENT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS parameter for that warehouse.
Probably a good idea to check this value before you change it, to make sure it is set to 15 mins and is therefore the cause of your issue.